# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe

Tags: selenium

I am getting below exception while trying to open a site

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe    at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:136)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>     at com.tst.Test.main(Test.java:12)

My code is:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Selenium/geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```

I am using selenium 3 with geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip. and java version is 1.8.

Please help me out

Comment: your gecko driver is at same location at you mentioned in code ?

Comment: check out C:/Selenium/ for geckodriver.exe file xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to open webpage on firefox browser in my macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670362/not-able-to-open-webpage-on-firefox-browser-in-my-macbook)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setPath properly for binary file. On windows, I prefer `\\` instead od `/`, Can you please try this?-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
```